# I am making a Bot in discord.py and when I run the project it points at bot.run('My Token') and says invalid syntax

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a Bot in discord.py and when I run the project it points at bot.run('My Token') and says invalid syntax. I have made sure that I am set the prefix using bot and not client. Please help

Here is the Error:
File "main.py", line 25
bot.run('My Token')
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Here's the Code:

```
import discord
from discord import Member
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions, Bot

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print('Bot is ready!')

@bot.command(name='ping', aliases=['latency'])
async def ping(ctx):
  await ctx.send(discord.Embed(title='Latency', description=f'{bot.latency} ms')

bot.run('My Token')
```

Comment: Can you show minimal code that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a parenthesis in the `await` line, you only closed one of the two:

```
async def ping(ctx):
  await ctx.send(discord.Embed(title='Latency', description=f'{bot.latency} ms')
```